# How to insert multiple items per GridView Cell

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-gridview

I'm new to Android.
I'm wondering how to insert multiple items in a GridView in the same cell.
Say an ImageView and a TextView.

Comment: @Unis..There are lots of example available on GOOGLE for the custom Gridview..plz refers that..have alook at these link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: and please remember: it's easier for people to help you if they have some [piece of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work on - always show us what you have tried so far

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi, thanks. That answered my  question. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply... **don't**. It's much more efficient to use a single TextView with a **compound drawable** inside (the less Views and ViewGroups you use, the better performances).